# Setting and Retrieving data from session with express

Tags: node.js, express, session

I am build a small application with node.js and express. In this application there are 2 routes on the backend, one for the users and one for the bugs that users can add.

My goal is to save the user on the session with sessionExpress and then retrieve it when whenever a bug is added to the system.

My code:

```
  app.get('/api/login',(req,res)=>{
    const user = req.body
    userService.checkLogin(user)
    .then(user=>{
        req.session.user = user   
        res.send(user)
    }).catch(err=>res.end(err))
})
```

here I'm saving the user to the session.

```
   app.post('/api/bug/', (req, res) => {
    const bug = req.body
  console.log(req.session.user)
    bugService.add(bug)
        .then(bug => res.json(bug))
})
```

On a different route, I'm trying to get the user back but req.session.user return undefined!

Any help would be much appreciated!

If any more code is needed please let me know

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var app = express()


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false,maxAge:null }
}))
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Comment: Can you post your server.js/app.js to show how you are initialising express-session middleware?

Comment: server.js is added

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it from http, can you do trust proxy: 1 and set secure to true. Otherwise cookie-parser will not recognise the cookies.

And from the front-end make sure you are making requests withCredentials.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the middleware in the wrong order. cookie parser should come before the session since express session uses cookies to save the session.

Note that you application router should come AFTER both of them